# java interface with no methods

Tags: java

I think I am falling into a rabbit hole.
Here is my situation.

I am planning on creating a somewhat generic event ApiRequestEvent that will get posted onto an event bus.  The event will have 2 fields:

```
ApiRequestRepository.Request  mApiRequest;
ApiRequestParams mApiRequestParams;
```

The receiver of the event will act like a "router".  It will to the following:

1. look at the request field and figure out which api call needs
   made
2. extract the correct parameters from the parameter object
3. call the correct api method with the parameters

What I am ending up with are several parameter classes that all "implement" the ApiRequestParam interface, but this interface has no methods.  I am just using the interface so I can pass in any of the parameter classes into the event constructor.

Maybe this is totally correct, but it just feels like I am doing something wrong and this should be done some other way.
Can someone explain what's wrong with this approach , or why it is right,  and if it is wrong , how it should be done?

Here some examples of the code I have so far.

The request event class

```
public class ApiRequestEvent {
    protected ApiRequestRepository.Request  mApiRequest;
    protected ApiRequestParams mApiRequestParams;

    public ApiRequestEvent(ApiRequestRepository.Request request, ApiRequestParams apiRequestParams) {
        mApiRequest = request;
        mApiRequestParams = apiRequestParams;
    }

    public ApiRequestParams getParams() {
        return mApiRequestParams;
    }

    public ApiRequestRepository.Request getRequest() {
        return mApiRequest;
    }
```

the interface with no methods

```
public interface ApiRequestParams { 

}
```

one of several parameter classes that will implement this "interface"

```
public class UserRequestParams implements ApiRequestParams {
    private String api_access_token;
    private User user;

    public UserRequestParams(String apiAccessToken) {
        api_access_token = apiAccessToken;
        user = null;
    }

        public UserRequestParams(String name, String email, String password, String passwordConfirmation) {
            user = new User();
            user.name = name;
            user.email = email;
            user.password = password;
            user.password_confirmation = passwordConfirmation;
        }

    }
```

creation of the event and posting it to the bus

```
mBus.post(new ApiRequestEvent( ApiRequestRepository.Request.SIGN_UP, new UserRequestParams(mName,mEmail,mPassword,mPasswordConfirmation )));
```

Comment: When you take a request off the bus, how do you use the params when you run it?

Comment: I guess my plan would be to cast the params into the type that should have been sent and then call the methods for that particular type

Comment: There isn't really a point. The only time I've seen empty interfaces is when a common type was enforced for readability and clarity for annotation processing. Other than that, functionally there isn't too much of a point.

Comment: @Qix so are you suggesting that I should just be passing in type Object?

Comment: If on the receiving side your processing is dependent on knowing the expected type of the parameter, then using the interface (which implies being able to treat parameters generically) is not only pointless, but, I would argue, actively misleading.

Comment: I think I understand.  My other option was to create a unique event type for each call, but that creates a lot of event classes.  So is that my trade-off?  I can use this generic event and not really be type-safe, vs a bunch of classes (I am leaning here and this is very helpful)

Comment: So just to be clear,  using the interface is not needed, I could probably just say the constructor takes an Object, right?  If that's the case, is this scheme just a bad idea in general, or just a trade-off I have to make?

Comment: Without having read the elaborate code and discussion: A so-called tagging interface is rare and one should reflect whether it is appropriate, but sometimes it **is** appropriate (cf. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html )

Comment: Using an interface in this way could be useful if you want to treat your parameters as object but ensure that only certain objects can be parameters, I guess.